# Equivalent struct declaration in Zig

Tags: struct, zig

How would you declare the following struct equivalently in Zig?

```
static struct lws_protocols protocols[] = {
    { "http", lws_callback_http_dummy, 0, 0 },
    LWS_PLUGIN_PROTOCOL_MINIMAL,
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } /* terminator */
};
```

Looking at the `LWS_PLUGIN_PROTOCOL_MINIMAL`, it's defined in a header as:

```
#define LWS_PLUGIN_PROTOCOL_MINIMAL \
    {  \
        "lws-minimal-proxy", \
        callback_minimal, \
        sizeof(struct per_session_data__minimal), \
        128, \
        0, NULL, 0 \
    }
```

and

```
struct lws_protocols {
    const char *name;
    lws_callback_function *callback;
    size_t per_session_data_size;
    size_t rx_buffer_size;
    unsigned int id;
    void *user;
    size_t tx_packet_size;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `zig translate-c -l libwebsockets minimal-ws-server.c > foo.zig` to produce a zig source file from the original C source.

I then looked through the foo.zig file and extracted the following:

```
pub const struct_lws_protocols = extern struct {
    name: [*c]const u8,
    callback: ?lws.lws_callback_function,
    per_session_data_size: usize,
    rx_buffer_size: usize,
    id: c_uint,
    user: ?*c_void,
    tx_packet_size: usize,
};

pub var protocols: [0]struct_lws_protocols = [0]struct_lws_protocols{
    struct_lws_protocols{
        .name = "http",
        .callback = lws.lws_callback_http_dummy,
        .per_session_data_size = @bitCast(usize, @as(c_long, @as(c_int, 0))),
        .rx_buffer_size = @bitCast(usize, @as(c_long, @as(c_int, 0))),
        .id = 0,
        .user = null,
        .tx_packet_size = 0,
    },
};
```

I then discovered that using the zig C header import:

`const lws = @cImport(@cInclude("libwebsockets.h"));`

I could just reference the structs (or other definitions) provided by the header by prefixing the names with `lws.` e.g. `lws.lws_callback_http_dummy` (as used above) rather than duplicating those definitions in my zig source

Comment: Also when you use `@cImport` the file gets translated and stored in `zig-cache/o/<some hash>/cimport.zig` so you can look there for what zig is doing.